# DateTime Formatting with Log4Net

Tags: datetime, log4net, datetime-format, log4net-configuration

I'd like to display a timestamp (HH:mm:ss) in a log file that's written using Log4Net. I want this value to be in Central Time, but I don't want the offset to appear. Ideally, I'd like it to read `<HH:mm:ss> CT`. Right now, my config is set up like this: `%date{HH:mm:sszzz}`, which is producing this `<HH:mm:ss>-05:00`. What would be the proper format specifier to produce this timestamp format?

Comment: .Net DateTime format strings don't support Time Zone names..

Comment: @Dan, did you manage to handle the date formatting in your log?

Comment: I haven't had the opportunity to try this out. I'm sorry...I know I need to accept your answer or comment with why it's not acceptable - I just haven't had the time. I have not forgotten, though, and I appreciate that you took the time to answer my question. I promise to follow with results ASAP!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stuartd said you cannot format DateTime with Time Zones natively. What you can do however is to create a custom `PatternLayoutConverter` that would use whichever rendering you need in the `Convert` method. For reference here is the Convert method for the `DatePatternConverter`:

```
// log4net.Layout.Pattern.DatePatternConverter
protected override void Convert(TextWriter writer, LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
{
    try
    {
        this.m_dateFormatter.FormatDate(loggingEvent.TimeStamp, writer);
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        LogLog.Error("DatePatternConverter: Error occurred while converting date.", exception);
    }
}
```

The `m_dateFormatter` field is initialized by options you can pass it by implementing the `IOptionHandler` interface.

Once you have your converter, add it to your layout by declaring it inside the layout tag

```
<layout ...>
    <converter>
        <name value="myDateWithTimeZone" />
        <type value="MyApp.LogConverters.MyConverter" />
    </converter>
    <!-- rest of the layout -->
</layout>
```

Comment: Still haven't taken the opportunity to test this out, but accepting this answer for completeness.