# How to log the level as a single letter in log4net?

Tags: logging, log4net, log4net-appender

Is there a way to change this configuration:

```
<appender name="appender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] [%-5level] %logger - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
```

... to log the log-level as a single letter like this:

```
DEBUG -> D
INFO  -> I
WARN  -> W
ERROR -> E
FATAL -> F
```

I tried `%-1level` but the number only controlls the number of characters to which to fill up with spaces. (`[%-5level]` means `[INFO ]` instead of `[INFO]`) So `[%-1level]` gave me `[INFO]` instead of the expected `[I]`.

**My ideas so far:**

***Variante 1***

I could configure a separate appender for each level where the level letter is set fixed for each level, all logging to the same file:

```
<appender name="info-appender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock"/>
  <file value="logfile.log" />
  <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelMatchFilter">
    <levelToMatch value="INFO" />
  </filter>
  <filter type="log4net.Filter.DenyAllFilter" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] [I] %logger - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
<appender name="warn-appender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock"/>
  <file value="logfile.log" />
  <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelMatchFilter">
    <levelToMatch value="WARN" />
  </filter>
  <filter type="log4net.Filter.DenyAllFilter" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] [W] %logger - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
.
.
<root>
  <level value="ALL" />
  <appender-ref ref="debug-appender" />
  <appender-ref ref="info-appender" />
  <appender-ref ref="warn-appender" />
  <appender-ref ref="error-appender" />
  <appender-ref ref="fatal-appender" />
</root>
```

***Variante 2***

I guess one could extend the `log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender` and override  the render method or if possible some other internal method which renders the level. (have not checked if thats really possible)

**Question:**

Is there an easier way to achive this? (just with configuration)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest solution, using the truncation format: `%.1level` instead of `%-5level` should truncate the output, as shown [here](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Layout.PatternLayout.html)

Alas, I didn't have time to test it live. Please see my initial answer below if it doesn't work.

EDIT: I didn't read the description of truncation correctly:

> If the data item is longer than the maximum field, then the extra
>   characters are removed from the beginning of the data item and not
>   from the end

which doesn't match what you need. Please have a look at writing a custom `PatternLayoutConverter`

---

Every pattern element is parsed based on a collection of `PatternLayoutConverter` that are used to process the pattern desired by the user. Your best bet would be to create a specific `PatternLayoutConverter` that would log the level formatted as you wish. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25789752/datetime-formatting-with-log4net/25803534#25803534) is an example where I explain the same principle to use a specific datetime format.

In your case it could be as simple as this:

```
public class MyLevelPatternConverter : PatternLayoutConverter
{
    protected override void Convert(TextWriter writer, LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
    {
        writer.Write(loggingEvent.Level.DisplayName.Substring(0, 1));
    }
}
```

Comment: you can pad with spaces left and right, but you can only truncate the beginning - strange that apache did not think someone might want to truncate the end as well - @samy: thanks for the answer, I will have a look into it, seems like that is my 2. solution done right ;-)

Answer (score 0):

See the document: https://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html

You can do it easily by formatter:

```
%.-1level
```

Although, the usage of negative numbers is strange here.